# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^2+1)^{1/n} = 1$ using definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

> **Question.** Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n^2+1)^{1/n} = 1$ using definition of a limit.

I can prove this using other means, but I need to show it using the definition of limit. That is, show

$$\left|(n^2+1)^{1/n} -1\right| < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting advice.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2+1)^{1/n}=1$ (`\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2+1)^{1/n}=1`)?

Comment: Write $\epsilon_n=(n^2+1)^{1/n}-1$ and notice that $$n^2+1 = (1+\epsilon_n)^n \geq 1+\binom{n}{3}\epsilon_n^3. $$ For $n \geq 3$, this gives the bound $$ 0 \leq \epsilon_n \leq \frac{6n^2}{n(n-1)(n-2)} \leq \frac{27}{n}. $$ This inequality will allow to find a suitable $N$ for each $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: This may or may not be a useful hint: $(n^2+1)^{1/n}=n^{2/n}(1+1/n^2)^{1/n}$